# How can I keep only the numbers in a variable in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a variable like this below:

G12345(@@)

How can I keep in the variable only the numbers 12345. I have done it before in PHP but I cannot find a way in Perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$v =~ s/\D//g;` should do the trick.

(Regular expression substitute "Not a number" with "nothing", globally)

Comment: It is a regular expression. It does a substitution. It substitutes "Not a number" with "nothing". It does it globally for every bit of the variable.

Answer (score 5):

This can also be done without regular expressions: [Transliterate: tr///](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $s = 'G12345(@@)';
$s =~ tr/0-9//cd;
print "$s\n";

__END__

12345
```

Answer (score 1):

Substitute any non-numeric characters with an empty string (\D is non-numeric):

```
$var =~ s/\D+//g;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way:

```
my ( $number ) = $string =~ /(\d+)/;
```

This means that were there some other digits to occur after the '(@@)' --for whatever reason, that you would not suddenly concatenate those digits to the number that lies between 'G' and '('. So the *capture* method makes sure you get the first set of *contiguous* digits.